# Android Wear Disconnection indicators

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-2.0

Does anyone know how to implement [disconnection indicators](https://designguidelines.withgoogle.com/wearos/components/disconnection-indicators.html) in a wear companion app?

I want to let the user know when the wearable disconnects from the handheld and vice-versa.

Thanks!

Comment: What aspect are you looking for help with? Detecting the dis/connect, displaying it to the user, something else?

Comment: Displaying it to the user. I was wondering if that disconnect message and the cloud icon is it somehow embedded in Android Wear, in some dependency. I managed the dis/connect part, using the CompatibilityClient

Comment: AFAIK it's not in a public API. You can get the icon here: https://material.io/tools/icons/?search=cloud_off